# AVAudioRecorder error "playback data format is unsupported" on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

The code below is throwing an OSStatus error 1718449215 which, according to the [Audio Queue Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117-CH5g-RCM0127), represents **"The playback data format is unsupported."**

The code works correctly if I change the `AVFormatKey` to be `kAudioFormatiLBC` or `kAudioFormatLinearPCM`. Is recording using kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE supported on iOS?

```
NSDictionary *settings = 
   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
   [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 32000.0],                AVSampleRateKey,
   [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE],  AVFormatIDKey,
   [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
   [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMedium],     AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
nil];

NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioRecorder *avRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] 
                                initWithURL:url 
                                settings:settings 
                                error:&error];

NSAssert(error.code != 1718449215,  @"The playback data format is unsupported.");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple docs, specifically the Multimedia Programming Guide ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html ), only lists the HE-AAC as a playback format. Regular AAC is listed for both playback and recording. So, it looks like HE-AAC only has partial support.